# SpriteKit didBeginContact not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision

I hope you can help, have a block moving across and it jumps to avoid obstacles and collect coins.
It's collision with the obstacles is working correctly and the below gameOver is working correctly.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    if ([contact.bodyA.node.name  isEqualToString:@"coins"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name  isEqualToString:@"coins"]) {
        [self coinCollected];   //THIS IS NOT WORKING
        NSLog(@"contacted"); //THIS IS NOT WORKING
    }
    else if ([contact.bodyA.node.name  isEqualToString:@"ground"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name  isEqualToString:@"ground"]) {
        [hero land];
    }
    else {
        NSLog (@"dead");
        [self gameOver];
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"gameover.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
    }
}
```

My PMWorldGenenerator file looks as below:

```
#import "PMWorldGenerator.h"
@interface PMWorldGenerator ()
@property double currentGroundX;
@property double currentObstacleX;
@property double coinX;
@property SKNode *world;

@end


@implementation PMWorldGenerator

static const uint32_t obstacleCategory = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t groundCategory = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint32_t coinCategory = 0x1 << 3;

+ (id)generatorWithWorld:(SKNode *)world {
    PMWorldGenerator *generator = [PMWorldGenerator node];
    generator.currentGroundX = 0;
    generator.currentObstacleX  = 400;
    generator.coinX = 50;
    generator.world = world;
    return generator;
}

 -(void)populate
{
    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
        [self generate];
}


-(void)generate
{
    SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.scene.frame.size.width, self.scene.frame.size.height/2.7)];
        ground.name = @"ground";
    ground.position = CGPointMake(self.currentGroundX, -self.scene.frame.size.height/2 + ground.frame.size.height/2);
    ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
    ground.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCategory;
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [self.world addChild:ground];
    self.currentGroundX += ground.frame.size.width;

    SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(10,10)];
        obstacle.name = @"obstacle";
    obstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.currentObstacleX/5, ground.position.y + ground.frame.size.height/2 + obstacle.frame.size.height/2 + 5);
    obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:obstacle.size];
    obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory;
    [self.world addChild:obstacle];
    self.currentObstacleX += 550 ;

    SKSpriteNode *coins = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
    coins.name = @"coins";
    coins.position = CGPointMake(self.coinX+80, ground.position.y + ground.frame.size.height/2 + obstacle.frame.size.height/2 + 25);
    coins.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = coinCategory;
    coins.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    SKAction *revolution = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI_4*10 duration:3];
    SKAction *repeatRotate = [SKAction repeatActionForever:revolution];
    [coins runAction:repeatRotate];
    [self.world addChild:coins];
    self.coinX += 550;

}
```

and lastly my PMHero file:

```
#import "PMHero.h"
@interface PMHero ()
@end


@implementation PMHero
static const uint32_t heroCategory = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t obstacleCategory = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t groundCategory = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint32_t coinCategory = 0x1 << 3;


+(id)hero
{
    PMHero *hero = [PMHero spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(12,12)];
    hero.name = @"hero";
    hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:hero.size];
    hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = heroCategory;
    hero.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory | groundCategory | coinCategory;
    return hero;
}
```

I have done exactly what I had done for my obstacles and ground for the `"coins"`, but it doesn't detect any collisions with them in my `didBeginContact`

Comment: what do you get if you try to log the body's name `NSLog (@"%@",contact.bodyA.node.name);`

Comment: obstacle for BodyA
hero for BodyB @jammycoder

Comment: so coins contact doesn't call the `didBeginContact` at all?? or does it fail the if statements?

Comment: @jammycoder nope, the other if statements work correctly, just not coins

Comment: does adding this do owt? `coins.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  heroCategory;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added your physics body for coins

```
SKSpriteNode *coins = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
coins.name = @"coins";
coins.position = CGPointMake(self.coinX+80, ground.position.y + ground.frame.size.height/2 + obstacle.frame.size.height/2 + 25);

coins.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWith...//need code here

coins.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = coinCategory;
coins.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
coins.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
SKAction *revolution = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI_4*10 duration:3];
SKAction *repeatRotate = [SKAction repeatActionForever:revolution];
[coins runAction:repeatRotate];
[self.world addChild:coins];
```

Comment: tried the above, but I'm afriad the coin now falls to the ground and the hero can't pass through it, and contact with it still doesn't result in didBegincontact being called.

Comment: do you need the coin to be dynamic??

Comment: seems contact is actually being made now. only problem is the coin being a solid object, how can i pass through it rather than bump into it?

Comment: if i turn Dynamic to NO, the coin floats in correct position but hero bounces off it. if i turn to YES coin drops and hero still hits into it.

Comment: Ok try updated answer, dynamic to NO and collisionBitMask to nil

Comment: I always have this trouble with spritekit it tends to be a lot of trial and error and getting things in the right places. Try collisionbitmask to 0 (not nil, as i said before) on both the bodys

Comment: Thank you @jammycoder, bit of trail and error and i finally got it. Hero collisionBitmast = groundCategory | obstacleCategory;
and coins.physicsBody.collisionsBitMask = 0; and Dynamic 0